# update part of plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, plist

I have a plist full of locations. I have the address and do not have the latitude or longitude. I want the application do geocoding when user want to view the detail of a location. However, I would also like the application to write the latitude and longitude back to the plist so that the next time I can skip geocoding. Is there a way to just write just two values in the plist back? The plist is in the document directory.

Any help or example project reference is much appreciated

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDictionary` has methods to read/write its content to a plist:

```
NSString* filePath = @""; // set file path here
NSMutableDictionary* pListValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

// modify pListValues here

BOOL success = [pListValues writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[pListValues release];
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually have complicated plist structure and I parse them into different data models. The longitude and latitude is embedded in the deepest data model. I tried to trigger my app to write the whole file from the top most data model. It returned failure with `writeToFile`. I think it's probably because I have other custom class reference in the data models.

Comment: From `NSDictionary` reference: "This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list." So you can use only these objects in your pList (they can be cascaded however).